# Can I find out store name given latitude, logitude coordinates in react native

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo

I am creating an iphone app, where I want to find out the store name from the latitude and longitude coordinates. Is there any such react native package that I can install ? BTW I am using expo platform.

Thanks,

Comment: You will need to use a third party API such as google-places api to get geocoding information.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! I have the longitude and latitude coordinates. Can I know the store name by passing the coordinates to the google APIs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Places API Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) that is available on Google Maps Platform.

This API will let you search for places within a specified latitude and longitude. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

For example in your case, you want to search for nearby "store" within 1500m radius of a point near Sydney, Australia: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.865111,151.196121&radius=1500&type=store&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Here are the different [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types#table1) you can use to refine your search request.

Please note that you will be needing an API key to authenticate each request to the API. Here is how you can get one: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

I hope this helps!